# can't import http in python 3.5.1 but it works in cmd

Tags: python-3.x, http

I'm still learning python. I have windows 8 and had downloaded 2.7 as well as 3.5 because two modules I used in the past respectively used different python versions. Now though, I'm trying to run a script where the first line is `import http.client` or `http`. Neither of these work though. In cmd, `python` returns 3.5.1 currently and `import http.client` and `import http` return with no errors but in my IDE these don't work. Why not?

Comment: My guess is that your IDE is using Python2 instead of Python3. There should be settings in the IDE that allows you to configure the version of Python to use.

Comment: could you direct me to those settings. I would like to be able to switch between versions if need be. I know that this isn't recommended for windows but it's helpful to know how in the event that it comes up.

Comment: which IDE do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the Pycharm documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) to change the Python version for your project from Python 2 to Python 3.

(In particular, *Selecting Python interpreter for a project* section)

Comment: Okay I've done this before and just for clarification: will I be able to move in between 2.7 and 3.5 depending on the project, despite whatever the CMD says the version of python is?

Comment: Yes! You can specify your Python version per-project.